# MVC - calling controller from view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to MVC

I am developing a web application using MVC and the application contains only one page.

So in that view I have to populate multiple data. Say if the application is a "News feed" application, i need to populate recent news, news liked by you, news recommended by your friends etc. So should I make a ajax call from view to all required controllers to fetch these data and append in the view??

Currently i am able to get the data by making an ajax call to controller and fetching the data, but as per my understanding, the controller is called first in a MVC and it renders the view and in the way i am currently using I am calling the controller back from view.

Is this method correct ??  what is the right approach to achieve this result in MVC?

If i have to use Ajax call to controller and get data, what is going to be the different in MVC?
In 3-tier app i will make ajax call to some web method or a Handler which will return some data
here I am calling an action result function which is again returning some data

Comment: you can use `@Html.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName")` to call each view in razor or you can use `ViewBag.PropertyName` to populate all data from different sources i.e ViewBag.Property1, ViewBag.Property2 ... in your `ActionMethod` and then in View, enumarte or get the resultset from `ViewBag`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can use ajax call like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#CategoryId').change(function () {
                $.getJSON('/Publication/AjaxAction/' + this.value, {},
                  function (html) {
                      $("#partial").html(html);

                      alert("go");
                  });
            });
        });
```

and then load a partial view from your contoller.

```
public ActionResult AjaxAction(int Id)
        {
            if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                if (Id== 1)
                {
                    ViewBag.SourceTypeId = new SelectList(db.SourceTypes, "Id", "Title");
                    ViewBag.CityId = new SelectList(db.Cities, "Id", "Title");
                    return PartialView("_CreateStatya");
                }
            }
            return PartialView();
        }
```

Comment: so what is going to be the different in MVC?
In 3-tier app i will make ajax call to some web method
here I am calling an action result function

Answer (score 3):

you can use [ChildActionOnly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.childactiononlyattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) :

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult GetLatestNews()
{
  //...
  return PartialView("yourView",yourquery);
}
```

and call that in your view this way :

```
 @Html.Action("GetLatestNews","Home")
```

Comment: But @Html.Action is not ajax call. Action GetLastestNews must be called by jquery and result (HTML code from partial) has to be inserted to the DOM. Or am I missing something?