# C# : Calling controller method from view folder

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax, filepath

I'm totally a noob to MVC Framework. And I want to call my Agentcontroller's action method which is in the Controller folder.

I'm trying to call

```
Controller/Agentcontroller/myactionmethod()
```

from View Folder

```
View/Agent/CodeGenerate.cshtml
```

I think I'm having trouble with the route but I can't find the App_Start folder. This is the script I'm using.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function G() {      
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: '/AgentsControllers/',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            success: function (response) {
                alert("Hi");
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

I've also checked this out as well: [MVC - calling controller from view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21155574/mvc-calling-controller-from-view)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: the class doesn't have a 'path' as such, it has a route - can you post how you've set your routes up?

Comment: Oops. Sorry about that. But I can't find the App_Start folder.

Comment: Agree with @alex you need to look at how your routes are setup. typically you would not use the url '/AgentsControllers', it will most likely just be '/Agent' and then depending on how your routes are setup will call a specific Method/Action on the Controller.

Comment: you have to use method name too in the url . url: ControllerName/methodName

Comment: You should use url: '@Url.Action("ActionName", "myactionmethod")'. it will generate proper url for you.

Comment: check below ans

Comment: Thanks y'all. I'll do some more reading on that. Much obliged!

Answer (score 1):

**Your Ajax call should be :**

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

    function G() {      
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: '/AgentsControllers/myactionmethod/',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            success: function (response) {
                alert("Hi");
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

**And your Controller Action Method Should be :**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult myactionmethod(YourModelName objYourModelobject)
{

return PartialView("~/Views/Agent/CodeGenerate.cshtml", objYourModelobject);
}
```

**And Your View Should be :**

```html
@model Application.Model.YourModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Agentcontroller", "myactionmethod", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "example" }))
{
    //HTML Helpers
     @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id, new { @id = "hdnDetailId" })
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="btnSave"><i class="fa fa-floppy-o"></i>&nbsp;Save</button>
}
```

Comment: Thanks buddy! I'll test it out now.

Comment: Please check and let me know if you require anything otherwise please accept this ans.